# Cómo averiguar el tamaño de la unidad en donde se encuentra una Base de Datos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero explicar brevemente el porqué. Sucede que la base de datos al cual lo actualizan o restauran desde otro servidor suele exceder el tamaño del disco o unidad en la que se encuentra al momento de dicha operación.

De modo que quiero saber si hay alguna manera de determinar el tamaño (o tamaño disponible) del disco o unidad en donde se aloja la base de datos.

Sólo he encontrado scripts para visualizar el tamaño de la base de datos, el log, tamaño disponible (en sí misma).

Comment: Con SQL no, con otros lenguajes de programacion si

Comment: @Fran de todas las preguntas que has realizado la mayoría no han sido aceptadas, por lo que veo, más de una te han sido de utilidad. Sugiero que si las respuestas te han sido de utilidad las aceptes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se me ocurren algunas:

### 1. Hacer un clásico `dir` sobre las unidades físicas

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''dir ' + LEFT(physical_name,2) + ''''
    FROM    sys.master_files AS f
```

Copiamos la salida y la ejecutamos, esto es compatible con SQL 2005 en adelante, en SQL 2000 no existe la tabla `sys.master_files` pero podemos reemplazarla por `sysaltfiles`

### 2. Usar `EXEC MASTER..xp_fixeddrives`

Esta activo creo que desde SQL 2000

### 3. Usar `sys.master_files` y `sys.dm_os_volume_stats`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT DB_NAME(dovs.database_id)      AS 'Database',
    mf.physical_name                AS 'Ubicación',
    dovs.logical_volume_name            AS 'Logico',
    dovs.volume_mount_point             AS 'Unidad',
    CONVERT(INT,dovs.available_bytes/1048576.0)     AS 'Mb/libres'
    FROM sys.master_files mf
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.FILE_ID) dovs
    ORDER BY 5 ASC
```

Pero solo para SQL2008 en adelante

Comment: Hola, la vesión del sql que manejo es: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64). Y pues, no me funciona para el último script.

Comment: La vista `sys.dm_os_volume_stats` solo esta disponible a partir del SQL2008 R2 según tengo entendido

Answer (score 0):

Has probado usar [sys.dm_os_volume_stats](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-volume-stats-transact-sql)

```
SELECT database_id, f.file_id, volume_mount_point, total_bytes, available_bytes  
FROM sys.database_files AS f  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(DB_ID(f.name), f.file_id);
```

Comment: Estoy manejando SQL Server 2008, y el script me amanda varías líneas en rojo, ¿Tengo que cambiar algún dato pertenciente a la base de datos al cual quiero aplicar?

Comment: Que versión exacta de 2008 estás usando? sys.dm_os_volume_stats se introdujo en el SP1. Si usas RTM no está disponible.

Comment: La versión que se usa en los servidores es: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)